# comparing variables in blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

i have $result variable which is to be checked if it exists in the $frnd variable

how am i able to do this in blade template

```
@if(!is_null($result))
<h4>Search Results &nbsp;&nbsp; ( {{ count($result) }} )</h4>    <br>
@foreach($result as $results)
<form role="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/friendlist">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <input type="hidden" name="friendid" value="{{$results->id}}">
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <ul><img class="smpic" src="/images/{{ $results->picture    }}">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            {{ $results->name }}
            </ul>
            </div>



        @if(Auth::user()->id != $results->id)
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <button class="btnz btn"> Add Friend </button>
        </div>
        @endif

            </div>
            <br><br>
            </form> 
        @endforeach
    @endif
```

i also include the $frnd variable in the compact() that is to be compared with the $results. what im trying to get is to put the "Add friend" button only to those not in the $frnd.

Comment: I do not understand your question. Is `$frnd` it's own variable, a property of `$results` or a property of `$result`? Is `$frnd` an array of `id`s?

Answer (score 3):

A generic way to check if a blade variables exists.

```
@if (isset($frnd)){
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <button class="btnz btn"> Add Friend </button>
  </div>
@endif
```

See the **[Displaying Data](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#displaying-data)** under **Echoing Data If It Exists.**

If you are looking to [check equality](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#control-structures).

```
@if (isset($frnd) && ($frnd->id == $result->id)){
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <button class="btnz btn"> Add Friend </button>
  </div>
@endif
```